# Alt-H key not working in KDE Plasma

Tags: plasma5

Recently I have installed Fedora 25 Linux with KDE Plasma 5.8.5.

Programs running in `konsole` or in `xterm` do not receive any keyboard input when <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> is pressed. All other <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> combinations are fine, but <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> does nothing. I have searched the keyboard shortcuts in the system settings, but do not see <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> bound to any function.

I have tried a different keyboard layout to rule it out as a problem source.

How can I check what is consuming the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> keypress or otherwise debug this issue?

---

*Quick check on the command line (i.e. in a terminal window): press `ctrl-V alt-X,` you should see `^[X` (i.e. [escape] X). Works for all letters except H on my system.*

---

**UPDATE**: Some weeks and few software updates later the problem is gone. I think it must have been a bug. The question how to debug such issue remains open.

Comment: Works here on FC25. What does ``xev`` report?

Comment: @phg Alt-J (for comparison) produces these events: Alt-L key press, J key press, J key release, Alt-L release. That looks good. But Alt-H is different. Alt-L key press, FocusOut, FocusIn, KeymapNotify, H release, Alt-L release. Could you decode what is going on there? If it is important, I will append the entire xev output to the question.

Comment: Just a note to my first comment. Alt-L means the left Alt key, and not the Alt key + the L key combination. Sorry for the confusing notation.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found an advice here: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/exvxqx/plasma_what_is_grabbing_my_alth_and_altk_shortcuts/:

> Settings > Workspace > Window Management > Task Switcher... Those two shortcuts for "Current Application" Forward and Reverse. Cleared them and all is good now...

Hope it helps to someone.